# Possible issue with PHP config?

Tags: php, xampp

I got a new laptop and installed a new version of XAMPP. I moved over a system I'm working on and it isn't functioning properly on this computer.

First issue I recognized was it doesn't include files from the location relative to the file that is including it. I have a `config.php` file in the `includes/` directory as well as my `include.php` file. In the `include.php` file I have to type `require 'includes/config.php';` even though the `config.php` is in the same folder as the `include.php`. On my other computer I just needed to do `require 'config.php';`.

Also since the included files didn't load with my main file which I am viewing, the variables and constants aren't defined, so it seems to be auto-defining them?

`Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Xion\includes\include.php on line 6`

Is this an issue with the config on a newer version of PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Usually PHP core setting `include_path` contains the current path as well: it's denoted by `.` (a dot), added to a list of included pathes:

```
include_path=".;c:\php\includes"
```

Quoting [the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path):

> Using a `.` in the include path allows for relative includes as it means
>   the current directory. However, it is more efficient to explicitly use
>   include `'./file'` than having PHP always check the current directory
>   for every include.

And yes, any barename (a non-quoted string) will be processed as a constant name by PHP. If this constant is not defined (like in your case), PHP will convert it to a string (issuing a notice, though).

Answer (score 0):

The notice error is because you are accessing an array like $someArray[DB_HOST]. Array keys should have quotes around them like $someArray['DB_HOST']. No quotes is a constant and keys are strings, not constant.

The include path issue is pretty standard too. If you have the following files:

```
index.php
includes/config.php
includes/include.php
```

If you load index.php and include the file `includes/include.php` you will have to type the full path `includes/include.php`. If inside of `include.php` you want to include `includes/config.php`. php treats the path as relative to where the original script is loaded which was index.php. Think about it like:

- In script, you load and run `index.php`.
- In `index.php` you include `includes/include.php`. This doesn't move you to `includes/include.php` but rather gets `includes/include.php` and brings the code into `index.php`
- All the code from `includes/include.php` runs as if from within `index.php`.
- You include `includes/config.php`. You are still technically in `index.php` and so you have to reference the file as if calling from within `index.php`.

To fix the include path, you can use the [set_include_path](http://www.php.net/set_include_path) function and add the full path to the includes directory (or relative to includes) and then you can drop the `includes/` from the path. PHP will just check if the file is in `includes/` if it can't find it anywhere else. You can also just change the [include_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) directive in php.ini or an .htaccess file.